# use matrix columns in linear fit

Tags: r

How to use one column of a numeric matrix as target variable and the remaining columns as predictors?

Somehow this doesn't work

```
# read matrix with 14 columns
d <- read.table("myfile.txt")

# target variable is last column
y <- d[,14]
x <- d[,-14]
my.fit <- y~x
```

Comment: There are at least a couple of major problems with your approach. Have you ever done a linear regression in R before? You don't give a function for controlling your data. Your independent variable is literally a pile of numbers. You might start by looking up "r linear regression".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
data(mtcars) #get some preinstalled data


model <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) #fit the model

summary(model) #get the summary
```

This does a linear regression of `mpg` against all other variables. No further processing required.